# Как вызвать событие на нажатие кнопки с атрибутом input[name]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.form-template-auto input[name="customer_phone"]').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-template-auto">
  <h2>Подробнее: </h2>
  <form>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
  </form>
</div>
```

Насколько правильно я написал? Почему-то не срабатывает. Кто знает, помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор не корректный был, вот так работает :

```js
$('input[name="customer_phone"].form-template-auto').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="customer_phone" class="form-template-auto"/>
```

UPD:

Как оказалось селектор таки был коректным, попросту значение атрибута `name` отличалось от того, которое вы использовали в селекторе

```js
$('.form-template-auto input[name="name"]').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('.form-template-auto input[name="phone"]').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-template-auto">
  <h2>Подробнее: </h2>
  <form>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нужно было сразу весь код вставить. У меня по прежнему не работает

Comment: @vKs в смысле сразу код вставить ? обьясните подробней плиз )

Comment: Я только что отредактировал свой вопрос. Там немного по другому отображается форма

Comment: @vKs дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Но почему "customer_phone" не подходит????, а только "phone"?

Comment: @vKs ну у вас в `html` разметке в теге стоит атрибут `name="name"` а селектор ищет по значению атрибута `name`